# Difference between 下る、下りる、下がる?

Tags: words, usage, meaning

I cannot, for the love of my life, understand the difference between

- 下る{くだる}
- 下りる{おりる}
- 下がる{さがる}

Don't they all mean the same, basically? Is there a difference, and if yes, how could I proceed to get it?

Comment: Meaning differences are pretty large. Can you give us more hints as to why you imagine their meanings are similar? What context are you talking about for your proceeding?

Comment: [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E4%B8%8B) is a good dictionary, although I don't think it's a replacement for an actual person answering.

Answer (score 25):

`おりる` and `くだる` both mean to move from a high place to a low(er) place.  The difference is that the former focuses on the end point/result, whereas the latter focuses on the movement and/or the course taken.  `さがる` means to go down or back, often used in relation to some value or standard.  You also use it when a part of something (bodily or other) lowers from its normal position.

Here are a couple of examples from my book (which I can't find in order to credit it):

```
　　　　　　　　　　|　おりる　|　くだる　|　さがる
――――――――――――――――――――――――――
急いで山を～　　　　|　　〇　　|　　〇　　|
小舟で川を～　　　　|　　　　　|　　〇　　|
舞台に幕が～ている　|　　〇　　|　　　　　|　　〇
成績が五番～　　　　|　　　　　|　　　　　|　　〇
一歩後ろへ～　　　　|　　　　　|　　　　　|　　〇
```

Here's a screenshot if it's misaligned in your browser (courtesy of @psosuna)

[image]

Comment: Since the diagram he put together looked funny on my display, I thought it would look funny to other people as well, so I aligned it to my machine and made an image of it that's correctly aligned. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWy0g.png